# Dynos field is blank after pushing Django app to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Programming newb, Trying to use Heroku for the first time for a Django app.  After I push it to Heroku, the Dynos field is blank.  I expected to see my procfile:  web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload

Of course, when I try to open the application on Heroku, I get:  An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details

Could this be because I don't have an extension on my procfile?

My Procfile should just be a file I created in my text editor, right?

Here is the log:

> 2014-01-06T07:34:17.321925+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/
>   host=aqueous-dawn-4712.herokuapp.com fwd="98.232.45.58" dyno= connect=
>   service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-01-06T07:34:17.778360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico
>   host=aqueous-dawn-4712.herokuapp.com fwd="98.232.45.58" dyno= connect=
>   service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-01-06T07:35:01.608749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/
>   host=aqueous-dawn-4712.herokuapp.com fwd="98.232.45.58" dyno= connect=
>   service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-01-06T07:35:01.868486+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico
>   host=aqueous-dawn-4712.herokuapp.com fwd="98.232.45.58" dyno= connect=
>   service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-01-06T07:46:57.862560+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/
>   host=aqueous-dawn-4712.herokuapp.com fwd="98.232.45.58" dyno= connect=
>   service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2014-01-06T07:46:58.114270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14
>   desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico
>   host=aqueous-dawn-4712.herokuapp.com fwd="98.232.45.58" dyno= connect=
>   service= status=503 bytes=

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you forgot to `heroku ps:scale web=1` ?

If not, could your Procfile be missing? Your Procfile should be name `Procfile` (no extension, capital P), and be placed in your project's root. You can check that by `heroku run bash` and then change in your app's directory and `cat Profile`.

Finally, if that's already the case then could your app have failed to start and gave up? Are there any other errors in the log?

Comment: heroku ps:scale web=1 returns heroku: command not found.  My file has no extension, and is capitalized.  The errors in my log are H14 errors.  I want to re-do my procfile and push it to Heroku to see if that changes anything.  Once I make the new file, how do I sent it to Heroku to update my app on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

with the `code=H14` in your log you can check the error at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

> H14 - No web dynos running
>   This is most likely the result of scaling your web dynos down to 0 dynos. To fix it, scale your web dynos to 1 or more dynos

You probably did not type `heroku ps:scale web=1` after `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issues. My 'heroku' account was not able to starting dynos. I create a new account on 'heroku' and its works perfectly.